# How to extract parts of response of AJAX from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Need some help here, i've been searching for related issues here but nothing seems to answer my problem. Ok so here how it goes

I have a simple search function that search through my database and I used an ajax to pass the data and get back the response and I manage to do that but my problem is that I can't seem to display the response the way I wanted to.

Here's my Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: url, /// defined url
    type: type, ///defined type
    data: data, ///defined data
    success: function(response){
    //here I want to display something like
         $('#display').html(the name of the employee);
    }
});
```

Here's the ajax response

```
{
    "employee": [{
    "badgeno": "123                ",
    "name": "John G. Doe",
    "success": true
}]
}
{
    "employee": [{
    "badgeno": "456                ",
    "name": "Jane G. Doe",
    "success": true
 }
```

I want to get the employee Name in there and display it in my page. How exactly am I gonna do that?

Thanks in advance. I'm still a newbie BTW

Here's the PHP

```
 $getEmp = $this->Employee_model->search_emp($employee);
    $count = count($getEmp);

    if($getEmp){
        for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
            $data['employee'][$i] = array(
                'badgeno' => $getEmp[$i]->BADGENO,
                'name' => $getEmp[$i]->NAME,
                'success' => true
            );
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
        print_r($data);

        //$this->load->view('admin/home', $data);
    }
```

Comment: Is that really the `ajax` response. I think it lacks some closing curly braces... or I don't know.... Maybe you can edit it a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
employee_name= data.employee[0].name;
$('#display').html(employee_name);
```

Link to fiffle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fcz53htw/
If you have more then one name, first add them to array, only then print then json_encode of the array.
Now its wont wont work because you printing twice.
Try change your php to this:

```
$getEmp = $this->Employee_model->search_emp($employee);
$count = count($getEmp);

if($getEmp){
    for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
        $data['employee'][$i] = array(
            'badgeno' => $getEmp[$i]->BADGENO,
            'name' => $getEmp[$i]->NAME,
            'success' => true
        );
        //echo json_encode($data);
    }
    echo json_encode($data);

    //$this->load->view('admin/home', $data);
}
```

Comment: sorry the response was undefined

Comment: Check now data.employee[0].name;

Comment: I'm adding a fiddle. one moment

Comment: meanwhile In the PHP, why you printing twice? Remove the  print_r($data);

Comment: If there is more then one name, Put them first into array, then print the array with json encode

Answer (score 0):

On php you are write the results twice delete the **printr** only use **`json_encode`**